# Can gpxpy write .gpx file?

Tags: python, gpx

I want to build a .gpx file and was hoping to use gpxpy.  I can see how to build such a file in memory, but I can't see how to write it out to disk.

Is it possible for gpxpy to write files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [gpxpy](https://pypi.org/project/gpxpy/) no, but with simple Python yes

Using the example of the [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/gpxpy/) page

```
....
print('Created GPX:', gpx.to_xml())
with open("output.gpx", "w") as f:
    f.write( gpx.to_xml())
```

(gpxpy uses [lxml](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/) or [elementtree](https://pypi.org/project/elementtree/) to parse .gpx files (in parser.py file))

Comment: Are you sure? https://pypi.org/project/gpxpy/#description says `# Creating a new file:`

Comment: @endolith gpxpy can create a string that represents contents of a .gpx file, but it has no functions to write the result into the file